# Reject only ssl_client_verify FAILED requests and allow SUCCESS/NONE

Tags: nginx, ssl, tls1.2, client-certificates

I'm enabling client certificate authentication in Nginx with `ssl_verify_client optional` option. I'm planning to allow the requests either if it is validated successfully or if there's no client cert submitted.

```
ssl_client_verify - SUCCESS allow
ssl_client_verify - NONE    allow
ssl_client_verify - FAILED  reject all failed cases
```

I've come up with the following regex to achieve the above

```
location / {
   if ( $ssl_client_verify ~ FAILED ){return 403 "Unauthenticated";}
   proxy_pass  http://app;
}
```

I'm not expertised in Nginx regexes. Hence, I just wanted to review whether this regex is secure enough to reject all possible failure cases. Almost all links on the internet [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/327002/how-to-use-ssl-verify-client-on-on-one-virtual-server-and-ssl-verify-client-off) [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/1068212/setup-nginx-to-require-certain-conditions-of-a-location-for-all-but-a-given-sour) tells to reject the request if it is not a SUCCESS like
`if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) { return 403; }`, but in my case, I want to allow both SUCCESS or NONE cases.

Please kindly check if my regex is secure enough to reject all failure cases, or please feel free to suggest an alternative to this.

Comment: *"I want to allow both SUCCESS or NONE cases"* - This requirement does not make any sense for me. If someone does not have the right certificate they can simply omit it completely.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for your reply. If a SSL intercepting proxy is in place, then we won't get the client certificate and in such cases, we have alternative authentication that will be done in the application side.

Comment: This make sense, thank you.